# Why running - `npx npm-run-all` throws "Cannot find module ..."?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular14upgrade

I am having issues with running the scripts for my sample angular app. The application was created with Nodejs 16.10.0 and npm version 6.23.2 with Angular CLI 14.2.10. I updated my nodejs to 16.13.0 and npm version 8.1.0. Angular CLI is 15.0.2. The issue is happening only with running my custom script. **ng serve** and **ng build** are working fine. Below is the error and I am unable to find the cause of the error.

I am trying to run the command **npm run test:precheckin**

**Error:**

```
> angular-app@0.0.0 test:precheckin
> npx npm-run-all build:int

Watching D:\angular migration POC\Angular14App\AngularApp and all sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore. Will not monitor dotfiles.
Found & ignored ./.angular ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./.vscode ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./dist ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./node_modules ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./src ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./angular.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./karma.conf.js ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./package-lock.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./package.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./README.md ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./tsconfig.app.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./tsconfig.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./tsconfig.spec.json ; is listed in .gitignore

Starting: test
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\angular migration POC\Angular14App\AngularApp\test'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Watching D:\angular migration POC\Angular14App\AngularApp and all sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore. Will not monitor dotfiles.
Found & ignored ./.angular ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./.vscode ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./dist ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./node_modules ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./src ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./angular.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./karma.conf.js ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./package-lock.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./package.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./README.md ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./tsconfig.app.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./tsconfig.json ; is listed in .gitignore
Found & ignored ./tsconfig.spec.json ; is listed in .gitignore

Starting: build:int
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\angular migration POC\Angular14App\AngularApp\build:int'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration int",
    "build:int": "npm run high:mem -- build --configuration=int",
    "test:precheckin": "npx npm-run-all test build:int",
    "high:mem": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code as text. Add full console output as well

Comment: @Konrad: I have updated my question with the code and full console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `npm-run-all` doesn't seem to work with `npx`

See these discussions:

https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/209

https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/218

This looks like a good workaround https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/209#issuecomment-847926286:

```
npx npm-run-all --npm-path npm other commands here
```

It would look like that:

```
"scripts": {
  // ...
  "test:precheckin": "npx npm-run-all --npm-path npm test build:int",
  // ...
},
```

But I would just install `npm-run-all` instead

```
npm install npm-run-all
```

and then

```
"scripts": {
  // ...
  "test:precheckin": "npm-run-all test build:int",
  // ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed my problem. I didnt see there was a compatibility issue with npx and npm-run-all. I need the npx hence I had used the 1st one u suggested.